# UICollectionViewCell -- make selectedBackgroundView bigger than cell itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionreusableview, initwithframe

I am trying to figure out a way to make my selectedBackgroundView of a cell, larger than the cell itself.

My following approach aims to make the selectedBackgroundView:
the cell's superview width (the entire width of the screen) **X** the cell's height

```
UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.superview.frame), CGRectGetHeight(cell.frame))];
bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bg;
```

When this cell is selected, the background color only extends within the cell's limits (not up to the superview's height)

How can I best accomplish making the selectedBackgroundView larger than the cell? Am I taking the complete wrong approach here?

Comment: The solution would be to turn off clips to bounds for all parent views of the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I tested, `selectedBackgroundView`'s frame is constant,  your `bg`'s width change does not work.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    CGRect f = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
    f.size.height += 20;
    f.origin.y -= 10;
    UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: f];
    bg.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: bg];
    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = false;
}
```